# Trying to remove a checkbox and accompanying <br> with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

See screen shot below:

I am trying to remove the option that is highlighted: "Invoice - Merchant Test" with jQuery.  The code for it is between the highlights in the screen shot.

I have had some success grabbing id's and hiding them, but it seems like I have to grab and hide three different id's and still there is a space where the `<br>` is when I remove them.

My question is:

How can I remove this option without writing several different jQuery statements, I prefer just one, and how can I remove the `<br>` that surrounds it so that when the option is hidden, it doesn't leave a big space?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in a single statement, with a chain of jQuery calls:

```js
$('#uniform-checkout_provider_checkout_cod')  //start with the original div
    .nextUntil('div')                         //then get the subsequent <br> 
                                              //and <label> elements
    .addBack()                                //and then re-include the original div
    .remove();                                //and finally remove them all
```

Reference:

- [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/): *"Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed."*
- [`addBack`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/): *"Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set, optionally filtered by a selector."*
- [`remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/): *"Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM."*

Comment: $("#uniform-checkout_provider_checkout_cod").nextUntil('div').addBack().remove();

Comment: TypeError: $(...).nextUntil(...).addBack is not a function

Comment: @Tron What version of jquery are you using? Pre 1.8 you want andSelf instead of addBack

Comment: So it works when I type it in the console, but it will not work when I stick it in the code, in this case, in script tags at the end to start with, then beginning, footer, etc.

Comment: also, when I try updating the jQuery library to 2.2.2, neither of those syntax versions work.

Comment: Perhaps the elements are being added dynamically and this code is being run before they are added - that's getting beyond the scope of what you originally asked though...

Comment: They are being dynamically added via an Ajax call that occurs mid way through the checkout process. I suggest placing the code in the relevant template file `Snippets/ExpressCheckoutConfirmation.html`, wrapping it in On Dom Ready. `$(function() { ... });`